# How to retrieve the data with using the Query from mongoDB and using the properties?

Tags: c#, mongodb, oop

I having some question about how to use the class and use it to grab the items from the internet.
(This question might be a little bit messy, please help to point out, i will try my best to state the question.)

```
class Person
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

class School : Person
{
  public string Cambridge { get; set; }
}

class Program
{

  public PersonRepository _personRepository;

  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    // Here i will call the function to retrieve information from the database
    var userData = _personRepository.QueryOne(x => x.Cambridge != null)
    return userData;
  }
}
```

Above is the mock function that i want to achieved can able to use the variable under the school and call from the database.
But it doesnt work as i expected.

I am getting the error `x.Cambridge`, the `Cambridge` is not found.
What is the term that call it and how to do made a change to support and use the variable under inherit class?

Thanks.

Comment: What does your `PersonRepository` look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following attribute `[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]` to ignore binding for fields that are unavailable in a document.

```
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class School : Person
{
     public string Cambridge { get; set; }
}
```

Regarding the inheritance, you may have to use `Discriminators`, more info about that is available [here](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/reference/bson/mapping/polymorphism/)

Here's an example though:

```
[BsonKnownTypes(typeof(School)]
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Nevertheless, I'm not a big fan of polymorphic classes (in your case, your design isn't polymorphic at all). You'd better not design your documents' structure that way. If I were you, I would do this:

```
public class Person {
    public String Name {get; set;}
    public School School {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: If for this, then i able to use it to call from my mongoDB? Want to ask more, my question title is ok?

Comment: @Ben: Yeah that does not affect anything maintained by MongoDB, it is only an attribute that defines to the driver to ignore extra fields because since Mongo is a No-SQL database, that case is very common and normal. If you have more questions, feel free to ask me :)

Comment: if i want to use the Person, can it be? Cause my current function already using the Person. But i want to Query one more for the Cambridge, is that possible still use the Person instead of the School?

Comment: @Ben: You have to add this attribute `[BsonKnownTypes(typeof(School)]` to the `Person` class as well.

Comment: Ok,  will try it later, will it have effect other existing function that do not require for the Person right? Thanks

Comment: @Ben: Nothing inside of MongoDb, but about your code, that's up to you to find out because it may or may not have such impact.

Comment: Because i have someclass that device, like one School, another one is Work. So if the situation is School, then wont have to include other like Work.

Comment: @Ben: What you are doing is wrong, because your design isn't polymorphic, I just tried to solve the problem non-destructively but if you wanna stick with that design you will soon face a lot of problems. Nevertheless you can add other types to the attribute `[BsonKnownTypes(typeof(School), typeof(Work)]`, but this is not right!